# как добавлять одну строку в таблицу с введенным значением

Tags: javascript, jquery

***задача*** заключается в том что я пытаюсь сгенерировать новые строки в таблице путем ввода в инпуте новую ссылку ( в моем примере доменный адрес), новые строки генрируются но при этом их больше чем должно быть, то есть генерится с учетом уже предыдущих значений; 
***Проблема*** состоит в том что в данном примере я при доавлении нового домена генерирую предыдущие значения (строки) вместе с новыми. Как мне переписать код чтобы я создавал строку только для вновь введенного значения.
Пример кода в [планкере](https://plnkr.co/edit/m7X4vCyK2p3zg475zBE9?p=preview) 
Ниже фрагмент js кода

```js
$(".check-all").click(function() {
  $(".check-domen").not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
$(".domain_inp").change(function() {
  var inpDomain = $(this).val();

  $("#createD").bind("click", function() {
    $("#tba").append("<div class='t-row'><div class='col-1'>" +
      "<input class='check-domen checkbox' type='checkbox' name='check-domen'>" + "</div>" +
      "<div class='col-2'>" + "<div class='wrap-c2'>" + "<i class='site-ico'></i>" +
      "<a href='#' class='domen-name'>" + inpDomain + "</a></div></div></div>")

  });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас создается дубликат ивента `$("#createD").bind("click")` при каждом введении в `input`.

```
$(".check-all").click(function() {
  $(".check-domen").not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$("#createD").bind("click", function() {
  $("#tba").append("<div class='t-row'><div class='col-1'>" +
    "<input class='check-domen checkbox' type='checkbox' name='check-domen'>" + "</div>" +
    "<div class='col-2'>" + "<div class='wrap-c2'>" + "<i class='site-ico'></i>" +
    "<a href='#' class='domen-name'>" + $(".domain_inp").val() + "</a></div></div></div>")

});
```